# Regular expression to isolate numbers from symbols and merge them as decimal numbers in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to isolate specific format groups within strings and convert them through JS or jQuery and regex, strings like these

```
#aba #abc #33-25
#02-20 #abe #abf
#abg #abe #00-50 #aba
#aja #255-45
```

to these

```
33.25€
2.20€
0.50€
255.45€
```

.

**1**. In regex level, my workaround so far for isolating #xx.xx groups within strings is

```
s = "#aba #abc #33-25"
s.match( /(#[W\d-]+)/ )    //["#33-25", "#33-25"]
```

It recognize the `#33-25` substring but outputs it 2 times in an array which is obviously insufficient.

.

**2**. Also how it will work (JS or jQuery) to    `(solved by @Kosh's answer)`

- remove # symbols
- replace hyphen symbol (-) to dot symbol (.)
- when #01-xx or #0-xx to convert to 1.xx or 0.xx (where x is obviously decimal numbers, always 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `match` and `replace`:

```js
const convert = (s) => s
  .match(/#0*(0|[1-9]+)-(\d\d)\b/g)
  .map(m => m.replace(/#0*(0|[1-9]+)-(\d\d)/g, '$1.$2€'));

console.log(convert(`#aba #abc #33-25
#02-20 #abe #abf
#abg #abe #00-50 #aba
#aja #255-45`))
```

Comment: I apologize to miss one step in my question where first comes the isolation. Your answer is completely correct for my initial question which I edited on its first part. Can you help on isolating these strings first?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
const texts = ['#aba #abc #33-25','#02-20 #abe #abf','#abg #abe #00-50 #aba','#aja #255-45'];
texts.forEach( x => {
  const m = x.match(/#(\d+)-(\d+)/);
  if (m) {
    console.log(x, '=>', `${m[1]}.${m[2]}€`);
  }
});
```

Here, `x.match(/#(\d+)-(\d+)/)` finds the first match of a `/#(\d+)-(\d+)/` regex (`#` matches a `#` char, `(\d+)` captures one or more digits into Group 1, `-` matches a hyphen and `(\d+)` captures one or more digits into Group 2) in a string, and then `${m[1]}.${m[2]}€` builds the final result where `m[1]` is Group 1 and `m[2]` is Group 2 value.